# Java spring hashmap to json

Tags: json, spring

I am creating a hashmap that holds key, value pairs. However, when I return a json it displays it as,

```
HashmapName: [{
      key: "keyName",
      value: "valueName"
            }]
```

However, I want it to return it as,

```
HashmapName: [{
      "keyName":"valueName"
            }]
```

Bean (xml) file:

```
<property name="name" type="java.util.HashMap&lt;String,String>" />
```

Java class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/value", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ObjectWithHashMap objectWithHashMap() {
     return object;
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: In Jackson it looks like in your second key when you just put an entry to your map. What library do you use?

Comment: updated with more information

Comment: Can you just replace `ObjectWithHashMap` by `HashMap<String, String>`?